# How to do string "not like" validation in view model in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

So what I like to do is:

```
   [NotLike(Value = "Forbidden value")]
   public string Title { get; set; }
```

Is it possible? I've read the docs from Microsoft and could not find anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `ValidationAttribute` and inherit from it as follows:

```
 public class NotLikeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string _NotLikeStr = "";
    public NotLikeAttribute(string notLikeStr)
    {
        this._NotLikeStr = notLikeStr;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (!((string)value).Contains(_NotLikeStr))
            {
                var memberName = validationContext.MemberName;
                var errorMsg = "Your Message";
                return new ValidationResult(errorMsg);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and decorate your property as follows:

```
 [NotLike("Forbidden value")]
   public string Title { get; set; }
```

of course instead of using line below

```
 if (!((string)value).Contains(_NotLikeStr))
```

you can `split string to multiple words` or use `Regular expression` or anything that meets your requirements .

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Any idea how to add custom error msg?

Answer (score 2):

I have two solution for you question:

**1. Use [RegularExpression()]**

You can use regular expression and create your own pattern for validation

For more information have a look at this link: [Data annotation regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578582/data-annotation-regular-expression)

**2. Create new Custom Data annotation**

You can create new custom data annotation (like what you did in question)

For more information have a look at this link: [How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression for this

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((?!Forbidden value).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```